# How to update $scope using jquery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I have a bootstrapper datepicker. I am updating the value of textbox in `hide` event. Textbox values changes successfully however `$scope` doesn't update.

**Javascript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnAdd').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            }).on('hide', function (e) {
                $('#hdnDays').val($(this).val());
                $(this).val('Add');
            });
        })

    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="c" id="hdnDays" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />
```

you can see that I am using `ng-model="c"` which means `$scope.c` should change, but it is not happening.

How to update `$scope` variable from `hide` event?

Comment: just a note that might help you with dev. there is a library of bootstrap written entirely in angular. Angular and JQuery dont play well together. [here is a link](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/l7wKCUSGJIwHLhz54tUN?p=preview

Comment: @JoeLloyd that's not true that angular and jQuery don't play well together. angular wouldn't convert jQlite (angular.element) to jQuery internally if that was true It's how you use it that matters

Answer (score 0):

in angular, DOM manipulation is done inside of a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), this is becuase you get two important variables you could use in there, and will solve your problem:

- you get a variable referencing your element, this way you do not have to relay on it's id, or some other selector,
- most important, you get a reference to the scope of the element, and this way you could call `scope.$apply()` when changes have been made in scope variables.

in your case, you should put your code in a directive, something like this:

```
app.directive('datePicker', function($parse) {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        }).on('hide', function (e) {
            scope.$apply(function(){
                $parse(attr['ng-model'])(scope).assign(element.val());
                element.val('Add');
            });
        });
    }
  };
});
```

and in the view:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary datePicker" value="Add" />
```

you might need to adjust this code depending on what it is exactly you need.